# what does the letter acronym S mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, minitest

what does S mean when running mini tests?

```
*** Running FRONTEND component engine specs
Run options: --seed 1947

# Running:

...................................................S....S....S.................................S............S...............S
```

I google around but didn't find an answer.

Comment: What does it say below the `....S...S...S...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you've skipped a test, or six in this case.

If you want to read more about skipping tests, there's a [good blog post here that goes into detail](https://www.paperlesspost.com/blog/teams/skipping-tests-minitest/).